# Sampling Standard Deviation

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Here I found a formula for the sample standard deviation:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html

Here is my simulation:

[image]

```
P[n_, σ_, s_] := 
  (2 (n/(2 σ^2))^((n - 1)/2))/Gamma[(n - 1)/2] Exp[-n s^2/(2 σ^2)] s^(n - 2)  

μ = 45;
σ = 12; 
n = 15;
list = {};
Do[
  data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], n];
  list = Append[list, Sqrt[Variance[data]]], 50000]

Show[Histogram[list, 100, "PDF"], Plot[P[n, σ, s], {s, 0, 35}]]
```

Can anybody explain the shift between the histogram and the P-curve?

Comment: Your `P` is not defined. Please make your code self-contained. As a first guess I would say that your `P` is not defined correctly, hence the deviation from the empirical distribution of standard deviations.

Comment: I added P from the cited site.

Answer (score 2):

Your `P` is the distribution of the *population* standard deviation, whereas your random standard deviations are *sample* standard deviations. They differ by a factor of $\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{N}}$. Correct for this by multiplying the sample standard deviations by this factor, and it's a match:

```
list = Table[Sqrt[(n-1)/n]*StandardDeviation[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], n]], {50000}];
P[s_] = 2(n/(2σ^2))^((n-1)/2)/Gamma[(n-1)/2]*E^(-((n*s^2)/(2σ^2)))*s^(n-2);
Show[Histogram[list, 100, "PDF"], Plot[P[s], {s, 0, 35}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My obvious mistake.

Comment: @azzteke it's not obvious at all.

Comment: I was irritated by equation(1) in that article, where there was a factor of 1/N